# Redis integration with spring boot JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm currently working on a CRUD application and aiming to incorporate industry-standard tools like AWS, MySQL, Docker, and more. For connecting with the database, I'm using Spring's plain old Spring JDBC Templates. However, I've noticed that many of Spring's tools are primarily built for Spring JPA.

I'd like to dive into the low-level details and utilize Redis as an in-memory database for caching. However, most tutorials I've come across focus on using Redis with Spring JPA. Could someone please provide me with a resource or guide on how to integrate Redis with Spring's JDBC Templates? I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

I have googled a lot of resources and all of them seem to be pointing to use spring JPA.

Comment: Try these ones https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-redis
and 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Redis can be integrated into spring boot very easily without Spring Data Redis dependency.

Use dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In Application create a bean of RedisClient/Helper

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RedisClient {

    private JedisPool pool;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
            poolConfig.setMinIdle(ApplicationConstant.REDIS_MIN_IDLE);
            poolConfig.setMaxTotal(ApplicationConstant.REDIS_MAX_TOTAL);
            poolConfig.setMaxIdle(ApplicationConstant.REDIS_MAX_IDLE);
            URI uri = URI.create(ApplicationConstant.REDIS_SERVER_URL);
            pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, uri);
            try (Jedis client = pool.getResource()){
                if (client.isBroken()) throw new JedisConnectionException("Unable to create Jedis pool please check the configurations.");
            }
            log.info("Redis connection established.");
        } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
            log.error("Error in creating jedis pool", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void close() {
        if (pool!=null && !pool.isClosed()) {
            pool.close();
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        try(Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            return jedis.get(key);
        } 
    }

    public String set(String key, String value) {
        try(Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
            return jedis.set(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now simply Autowire/inject the bean wherever you want.

```
@Repository
public class MyDao{

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    private RedisClient redisClient;

    public String getData(String key) {
        String obj = redisClient.get(key);
        if (obj != null) {
           return obj;
        }
        String result= em.find(String.class, key);
        redisClient.set(key, result);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Reference- https://redis.io/docs/clients/java/,
https://www.baeldung.com/jedis-java-redis-client-library